# CSS @media img [data] not work?

Tags: css, image, media-queries

I running this img code for different screen resolution

```
<img src="http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/grey_wash_wall.png"
data-src-400px="http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/dark_wood.png"
alt="">

@media (min-width: 400px) {
   img[data-src-400px] { 
      content: attr(data-src-10px, url); 
   }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEqbbQ

but it give an error in my chrome, it says **"invalid property value"**. Screenshot: [image]

what happens and why it didnt work??

Comment: [Void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) can't have pseudo-elements.  `img` is a void element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `content` is only applied to pseudo elements. [**SPEC**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting)

> The '::before' and '::after' pseudo-elements are used to insert content immediately before and immediately after the content of an element (or other pseudo-element). The 'content' propety is used to specify the content to insert.

2. Just a remind (which may be irrelevant). `<img>` cannot have `:before`/`:after` pseudo elements (it cannot have decendant elements at all).

Comment: 2 is probably irrelevant to what the OP is trying to accomplish, but yeah.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep, just a remind for OP not to try pseudo elements either.